# Compact paratopological groups are automatically topological groups.

Tags: topological-groups

A compact paratopological group is a topological group.
How to prove it?

An abelian paratopological group is a topological group. Is this right?

A paratopological group is a topological semigroup that is algebraically a group. In other words, it is a group $G$ with a topology such that the group's product operation is a continuous function from $G × G$ to $G$. This differs from the definition of a topological group in that the group inverse is not required to be continuous.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you assuming that the topology is Hausdorff?

Comment: In fact, even each locally compact paratopological group is a topological group (see [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/209491/1770)). [(Quasi)regular pseudocompact paratopological groups are topological groups too](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2001).

Comment: Commutativity rarely helps to prove that a paratopological group, possessing some additional topological properties, is topological. In this branch most positive results are proved both for abelian and non-abelian groups and most counterexamples are abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, even if $G$ is not assumed Hausdorff.  For a proof, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/209491/1770).  The $T_1$ case is elementary, though the general case seems to require some work.

The answer to the second question is no.  [Another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/142026/1770) in the same thread gives an example of a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for which addition is continuous, but $x\mapsto -x$ is not continuous.

If you want an example of an abelian Hausdorff paratopological group that is not a topological group, there appears to be an example in the first link I posted, which uses some kind of $p$-adic positive cones on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So the answer to the first question is "yes and no"? I didn't realize paratopological groups were related to [paraconsistent logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro In both cases I was obviously referring to the first question that I hadn't yet answered.  I've updated to the more standard terminology of static ordering.

Comment: A standard example of an (abelian) paratopological group failing to be a topological group is the Sorgenfrey line, that is the real line endowed with the Sorgenfrey topology (generated by the base consisting of half-intervals $[a,b)$, $a<b$).